# rdlc Asp.NET MVC 4 отчет

Tags: asp.net

Такая проблема
написал код , создал отчет
создал dataset в datasete таблицу с полями которые возвращаются из ХП 
в отчете подключил dataset и data Sources 
никаких ошибок не выводит но не печатает данные которые приходят из ХП переменная result 
что может быть не так

```
    List<REPORT_TSR_HAVE_class> result = new List<REPORT_TSR_HAVE_class>();

    if (AccessGrand == 1)
    {
        WebCBIServiceClient client = new WebCBIServiceClient();
        result = client.REPORT_TSR_HAVE("01.01.2015","01.05.2015");
        client.Close();

    }
    else { return View("~/Views/Account/Logon.cshtml"); }
    LocalReport local = new LocalReport();


    local.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reports/REPORT_TSR_HAVE.rdlc");
    ReportDataSource dataSourse = new ReportDataSource("ForReport", result);
   //dataSourse.Name = "Report";
    //dataSourse.Value = result;


    local.DataSources.Add(dataSourse);
    //word
    //Exel
    //Image
    //new ReportDataSource("REPORT_TSR_HAVE", result)
        string type_rep = "PDF";
        String reportType = type_rep;
        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String fileNameExtension;

        string deviceInfo =

"<DeviceInfo>" +
"  <OutputFormat>" + type_rep + "</OutputFormat>" +
"  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
"  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
"  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
"  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
"  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
"  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
"</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        renderedBytes = local.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);
        return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
```

Comment: 1. Ваш вопрос невозможно повторить/возпроизвести.  Что такое, например result? Не пустой ли он.  2. Что содержит warnings и streams после вызова?

Comment: 1.result получает данные из хранимой процедуры, не пустой во время отладки проверял

Comment: в отчете rdlc  подключен датасет

Comment: Что содержит warnings и streams после вызова? - не могу сказать код брал из другого проекта и  интернета

Comment: Какой тип данных у result? Попробуйте преобразовать его в `DataTable`, или `List<ClassWithPublicProperties>`

Comment: Вы всётаки посмотрите[2], может в них содержится информация об ошибке.

Comment: result  - тип List <Класс>  
[2]- как посмотреть ? по отладке после выполнения 
 return File...  - пустой нет ни каких ошибок

Comment: Можно посмотреть отладчиком (Clrt+Alt+Q).

Comment: Попробуйте `xls` ексель всегда есть, а pdf возможно у вас отключен.

Comment: warnings--{Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[0]}

Comment: //Exel   - менял    тоже самое все что набрано вручную отображается а данных из бд нет

Comment: все что набрано вручную - имеется ввиду в rdlc? Может у вас проблема с передачей данных в REPORT_TSR_HAVE_class или в функции REPORT_TSR_HAVE. Либо не правильно записано выражение в rdlc.

Comment: streams--{string[0]}

Comment: функция работает проверял, 
 ReportDataSource dataSourse  - который принимает значение  по отладчику видно след.
vall - Count(64)
и пошли данные из процедуры

Comment: выражение в rdlc   - просто перетянул колонку  и вручную писал и по разному

Comment: В rdlc должна быть строчка вида  `<Value>=Fields!Your_Field.Value</Value>` (если смотреть в xml варианте)

Comment: есть такая строка